# Ejecutar JNI en Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

Hola he estado trabajando en JNI con Windows pero ahora me toca migrar todas las pruebas que he realizado a ubuntu, alguien me podria ayudar en decirme que es lo que ocupo? supuestamente tengo los pasos para crear el header con javac y javah pero la parte de Cde la libreria dinamica es donde tengo muchas dudas de como hacerlo

Comment: Te recomiendo este tutorial está en español, solo necesitas gcc instalado en ubuntu http://www.macprogramadores.org/documentacion/jni.pdf

Comment: Gracias pero ese documento ya lo lei y en ese base lo que ya programe, pero no entiendo la parte especifica de compilar y todo el proceso de c en ubunto

Comment: Que comandos has intentado ? En mi caso no encontraba JNI.h por lo que agregé el comando -I/ruta/al/JNI.h

Comment: gcc -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux/ -o libHolaMundo.so HolaMundo.c -Wall                                -este es el que acabo de encontrar creo que funcionara-

Comment: Podrías decirnos si funcionó?

Comment: al quererlo ejecutar me salen los errores de: 1----bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/: No such file or directory----2-------bash: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux: No such file or directory--3-----gcc: error: -E or -x required when input is from standar input

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48250/discussion-between-ajeno-and-edu-arias).